# codeigniter shopping cart is not saving decimal qty value

Tags: codeigniter, cart

**codeigniter shopping cart is not saving decimal qty value, If the user inputs 2.5 as qty it accepts as 25. so how to make qty as double or float type.
in side cart system library i have changed**

```
$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $items['qty']));
```

**to**

```
$items['qty'] = trim(preg_replace('/([^0-9\.])/i', '', $items['qty']));
```

**but nothing changed. please i need help!**

Comment: What is the type of attribute for the price and quantity in the database?

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you don't use it because it is  DEPRECATED**

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html

you can see in this link

Comment: what dos it mean DEPRECATED

Comment: codeigniter don't support this library anymore so you have to maintain it your self.They have this library now only for older versions.

Comment: you have to go through the core classes of this library which I suggest is not a good idea build your own shopping cart according to your requirement if you don't want to build it your self here is a link for shopping cart library

Comment: May be this will help your answer is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754145/decimal-quantity-in-codeigniters-shopping-cart